# Calculate a column values based on another column value in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I am having an array named `$results` values as follows,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [group_name] => Ist Term - LKG
            [group_id] => 69
            [parent_group_id] => 0
            [amount] => 3200
            [group_type] => I SEM TUTION FEES; II SEM TUTION FEES; SPORTS FEES; CONCESSION
            [group_amount] => 1000.00; 2000.00; 300.00; -100.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [group_name] => IInd Term - LKG
            [group_id] => 70
            [parent_group_id] => 0
            [amount] => 450.00
            [group_type] => MAGAZINE, PHOTOS,BAG, ID etc ; CO - SCHOLASTICS; BOOKS, NOTEBOOKS, UNIFORM
            [group_amount] => 200.00; 150.00; 100.00
        )

)
```

And i am displaying results in a table like,

```
<?php echo
    '<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

    <tr>

    <th>Group Name</th>
    <th>Group Type</th>
    <th>Group Amount</th>
    <th>Total Amount</th>
    <th>Actual Pay</th>

    </tr>';
    foreach($results as $key){

      echo
      '<tr>

       <td>' . $key['group_name'] . '</td>' .
      '<td>' . $key['group_type'] . '</td>' .
      '<td>' . $key['group_amount'] . '</td>' .
      '<td>' . $key['amount'] . '</td>' .
      '<td>' . 300 . '</td>' .

      '</tr>';

    }

    echo
    '</table>';

    ?>
```

Which gives table structure like,

[image]

Here the Total Amount 3200 and 450 each comes from sum of Group Amount respectively like,

```
1000.00; 2000.00; 300.00; -100.00 => 3200

200.00; 150.00; 100.00 => 450
```

Now the Actual Pay column has the value of 300 in both fields which means user was able to pay only 300 from the total amount, and hence I am in the need to display the values based on actual payable.
Say here actual payable is 300 and the group amount needs to split up from the existing group amount accordingly as like below and its the desired output I am expecting,

First Group:

```
1000, 1900, 0, 0
```

Second Group:

```
150, 0, 0
```

I am in the need of the Group Amount to display like above in a table based on the actual pay, there needs to be a split up inside the group amount.

Kindly help me to achieve the result like I have mentioned above and as I am new in PHP I am expecting a more helpful support to achieve this. And any good help would be much more appreciable.

Comment: Is actual pay static or fixed amount?

Comment: @GufranHasan, It may vary and its not a static amount.

Comment: Here is your code as I am seeing it's 300 static.

Comment: Your first group is correct right? Because it seems like the logic doesn't match what you are generating when you are writing your second group. Either way this is going to be rather difficult of a task to do in php and I doubt someone is going to take the time to write the code. I would suggest trying to accomplish this yourself and post a question when you are further along.

Comment: @GufranHasan, Yes i have given as static here in order to make confusion inside code as its coming from another variable and no problem if you give me result with this static value of 300.

Comment: @Alex, As i am very beginner in PHP i am unable to get to move further along with it. And hence asking for a help.

Comment: Shouldn't first group be 1000,1850,0,0? If not it would be best if you could write out a formula of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Alex, Yes it can be like ```1000,1900,0,0``` (as actual pay is 300 edited in question)..

Comment: Then why did you write 300.00; 0; 0; 0... I'm having trouble understanding that

Comment: @Alex, Changed in question. I am in the need of split up from  Group Amount with actual pay and that is the need for me.

Comment: Is it also possible to take the number in groups 4 and divide total pay by that 300/4 = 75 and subtract that from each group?

Comment: @Alex, Yes we can do it in that way also, as you are experienced i hope you could help me in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your code and written some logic to calculate group amount. Please try this one:

```
 echo
    '<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

    <tr>

    <th>Group Name</th>
    <th>Group Type</th>
    <th>Group Amount</th>
    <th>Total Amount</th>
    <th>Actual Pay</th>

    </tr>';
  $payamnt = 300;
    foreach($results as $key){
       $rest_amnt = $key['amount']-$payamnt;
       $group_amount = explode(" ",$key['group_amount']);
        $bramnt=array();
        foreach($group_amount as $gamt){
        $bramnt[] = rtrim($gamt,";");
        }
        $garr='';
        if(in_array($rest_amnt,$bramnt)){
       //print_r($bramnt);
       // echo count($bramnt);
        //echo $rest_amnt;
            $garr .=$rest_amnt;
            for($i=0;$i<count($bramnt)-1;$i++){
                   $garr .= ', 0';
            }
           // echo $garr;
        }else{
              $calval = $rest_amnt-$bramnt[0];
            $garr .=$bramnt[0];
            $garr .= ', '.$calval;
            for($i=0;$i<count($bramnt)-2;$i++){
                   $garr .= ', 0';
            }
            //echo $garr;
        }


      echo
      '<tr>

       <td>' . $key['group_name'] . '</td>' .
      '<td>' . $key['group_type'] . '</td>' .
     // '<td>' . $key['group_amount'] . '</td>' .
     '<td>' . $garr . '</td>' .
      '<td>' . $key['amount'] . '</td>' .
      '<td>' . 300 . '</td>' .

      '</tr>';

    }

    echo
    '</table>';
```

Output:

```
Group Name  Group Type  Group Amount    Total Amount    Actual Pay
Ist Term - LKG  I SEM TUTION FEES; II SEM TUTION FEES; SPORTS FEES; CONCESSION  1000.00, 1900, 0, 0 3200    300
Ist Term - LKG  I SEM TUTION FEES; II SEM TUTION FEES; SPORTS FEES; CONCESSION  150, 0, 0   450 300
```

Comment: Please try this logic

Comment: I am glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

This function will divide out the paid amount among (pag) groups (taking into account any negatives in the groups) and subtracting the pag from each group:

```
function getvals ($values = array(), $paid = 0) {
    if ($paid == 0) {
        return $values;
    }

    $paid = abs($paid);

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($values as $val) {
        if ($val <= 0) {
            $paid-=$val;
            continue;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if ($i == 0) {
        return $values;
    }

    $frm = $paid / $i;

    foreach ($values as $val) {
        if ($val <= 0) {
          $data[] = 0;  
        } else {
          $data[] = round($val - $frm,2);
        }
    }

    return $data;
}


$values = array(1000,2000,300,-100);

$paid = 300;

$data = getvals($values, $paid);

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this i have try to solve your problem by that logic:

```
echo
    '<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

<tr>

<th>Group Name</th>
<th>Group Type</th>
<th>Group Amount</th>
<th>Total Amount</th>
<th>Actual Pay</th>

</tr>';
    foreach($results[0] as $key){

       $new_group_amount = getGroupAmount($key['group_amount'],300);

        echo
            '<tr>

   <td>' . $key['group_name'] . '</td>' .
            '<td>' . $key['group_type'] . '</td>' .
            '<td>' . $new_group_amount . '</td>' .
            '<td>' . $key['amount'] . '</td>' .
            '<td>' . 300 . '</td>' .

            '</tr>';

    }

    echo
    '</table>';


function getGroupAmount($group_amount,$actual_amount){


    $group_amount_array = array_reverse(explode(";",$group_amount));


    $balance = $actual_amount;
    foreach ($group_amount_array as $group_amount_arr ){


        if($balance > 0 ) {
            $new_group_amount [] = ($group_amount_arr > 0 && $group_amount_arr - $balance > 0) ? $group_amount_arr - $balance : 0;
        }else{

            $new_group_amount [] = $group_amount_arr;
        }
        $balance -=$group_amount_arr;


    }

   return  implode(";",array_reverse($new_group_amount));

}
```